# Symbol for twice differentiable functions

Tags: functional-analysis, notation

Is there a symbol for the set of twice differentiable functions (2nd derivative not necessarily continuous)? I believe the symbol for twice ***continuously*** differentiable functions is $C^2(\mathbb F)$? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Given your tag of functional analysis, the following might be of interest for you:

The Sobolev space $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ is the set of all functions $f \in L^p(\Omega)$ such that for every  multi-index $\alpha$ $|α| \leq k$, the weak partial derivative $D^\alpha f$ belongs to $L^p(\Omega)$.

More details in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space).